# Functions satisfying $f(x) = y$ with $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

All continuous function $f$ from the open interval (0,1) to $\mathbb{R}$ takes a rational value: $f(x) = r\in\mathbb{Q}$;  however, it is not sure that the pre-image $f^{-1}(r)$ of the rational r contains a rational. For example it is known that $f(x)=\tan x$ (as well as $\log x, \sin x, \cos x$  and others) is transcendental for x algebraic nonzero thus none rational $s\in (0, 1)$ such that $\tan s=r$. On the opposite side, for example, the image of every rational in the domain of definition of any ratio of polynomials (rational function) is always a rational.

*How to determine the set of functions $f$  -note it S - from (0, 1)  in $\mathbb R$ satisfying the property: "There exists a rational s such that $ f (s) $ is rational "?*

We know that the set $R$ of ${\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}}$ where $p, q\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, is contained in S but it seems that $S\setminus R\neq\phi$.